# Computationally-heavy Thread is "hanging" in Python 3 - Why is that?

Tags: python, multithreading, blocking

I am relatively new to Python, but a little skilled at coding. This little piece of code is driving me crazy. Why on earth is the method **summe()** so stubborn in a Thread? The Threads seem to be processed *sequentially*. That means, every next Thread is only started if the previous one has come to an end. I don't know why? All four Threads should start "parallelly" and work "parallelly". Even if they are running only on a single Core due to the restrictions of [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

The same procedure with the method **count()** works "*parallelly*" as intended.

Dear Internet, please help me!…

Paul:)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import threading

# Hanging...
def summe(n):
    print("Start")
    s = sum(range(n))
    print("Done")

# Works like a charm
def count(n):
    print("Start")
    while n > 0:
        n = n-1
    print("Done")

# This works
for i in range(3):
    threading.Thread(target=count,args=(10000000000000,)).start()

# This hangs...
for i in range(3):
    threading.Thread(target=summe,args=(10000000000000,)).start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the GIL, a built-in function like `sum` is atomic; once it starts, it won't be interrupted until it completes. While it is *possible* that the threading system could choose to execute only the first line of `summe` before switching context to allow the next thread to start, it is highly unlikely. The "hang" you see is `sum` in the first thread blocking until it finally completes.

In `count`, on the other hand, there is no one long atomic operation that blocks on the GIL; just lots (and lots and lots and ...) of small operations, which allows lots of opportunity to start each thread and return to the main thread. Using a much smaller value for `n`, you can see each `count` thread start, then a few moments later they will complete. Likewise, you can observe the three `summe` threads run almost serially (in one test I ran, the first ran to completion before starting the other two running in parallel).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very fast answer. My problem is, the the real method (sum() was just an example) I use is written in Cython, very big and obviously atomic too. Is there a way to force such an method to be not atomic?

Comment: @Paulquappe Sounds like you might be better off parallelizing your Cython function. If you can get rid of your Python API calls then you can release the GIL and implement proper concurrency using OpenMP.

Comment: Many, many thanks. I think that sounds like a plan.